# How to put asterisks on for looping

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

```
  System.out.println("Enter your number");
    int num = scanner.nextInt();
    
    int count = 1; 
    for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) { 
    for(int j = 1; j <= 1; j++) { 
    for(int k = 1; k <= count; k++) {
System.out.print(k + " "); 
}
System.out.println(); 
count++;
```

this is what i need to have but i cant seem to put the asterisk

[image]

Comment: I suggest you divide the task into smaller parts. First create a program that write the correct number of lines. Hard-code output of `"1"` on each line. Then inside the loop to print the lines, add the counting of the numbers. Then, as a separate loop after the numbers, add the asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

Much like `System.out.print(k + " ");` you can use `System.out.print("*");` to print an asterisk. It isn't clear why you would try `for(int j = 1; j <= 1; j++) {`, that will only run once (so it isn't really a loop). You need a second inner loop, not another level of nesting. Like,

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your number");
int num = scanner.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) { // From 0 to i + 1 the #
        System.out.print(j + 1);
    }
    for (int j = i + 1; j < num; j++) { // From i + 1 to num a *
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
Enter your number
7
1******
12*****
123****
1234***
12345**
123456*
1234567
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class Simple{
public static void main(String args[]){
int i, j,number,n=7;   
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {   
   number=1;   
   for(j=0; j<=i; j++)  {   
      System.out.print(number+ " ");   
      number++;   
   }   
   for(j=i+1; j<n; j++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
   System.out.println();  
}
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take on it using a single `for` loop:

**Using simple string concatenation:**

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    
System.out.println("Enter your number");
int num = userInput.nextInt();
    
// Using String Concatenation
String numSet = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    numSet += String.valueOf(i);
    System.out.println(numSet + String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(num-i, "*")));
}
```

**Or by using the StringBuilder class:**

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    
System.out.println("Enter your number");
int num = userInput.nextInt();

// Using StringBuilder:
StringBuilder numberSet = new StringBuilder("");
StringBuilder overAll = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    numberSet.append(i);
    overAll.append(numberSet.toString())
               .append(String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(num-i, "*")))
               .append(System.lineSeparator());
}

System.out.println(overAll.toString());
```